# Android design - RelativeLayout (background color)

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I've the following RelativeLayout but i would like to improve it. (make a nice design)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+navigate/RLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ABABAB"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/hcorpo" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/hcorpo"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />.
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/hotelinfos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hcorpo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hcorpo" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/hotelname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hotelinfos"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelinfos" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/hoteladdress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hotelname"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelname" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/hotelphone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hoteladdress"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hoteladdress" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#12C"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#12C"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:id="@+id/hotelemail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hotelphone"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelphone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:id="@+id/bookinginfos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hotelemail"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelemail"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/pnr"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bookinginfos"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bookinginfos" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/segmentCode"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bookinginfos"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pnr"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/checkin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pnr"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pnr" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/checkout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pnr"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkin"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/nights"    
        android:layout_below="@+id/pnr"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/roomType"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkin"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkin" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/boardBasis"
        android:layout_below="@+id/roomType"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/roomType"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/paxNames"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boardBasis"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/boardBasis" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:id="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/paxNames"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/paxNames" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/supplierCode"
        android:layout_below="@+id/forHotel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/forHotel" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/picture" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/hcorpo"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hcorpo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to do something like the tripadvisor app: http://hpics.li/d961aa3
explanation:

For example i would like to put the following part in a nice white rectangle:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/hotelinfos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hcorpo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hcorpo" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/hotelname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hotelinfos"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelinfos" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/hoteladdress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hotelname"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotelname" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/hotelphone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hoteladdress"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hoteladdress" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#12C"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

Should i create a new RelativeLayout with another background color?

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get round rectangles as background in any layout, you can use 9 patch PNG images or use shape class to create custom drawables.

Just check my sample code below, it may useful to you.

**main.xml** in layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Testing white rectangle"
            android:textColor="#f00"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="25dip" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Testing white rectangle"
            android:textColor="#0f0"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="25dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**bg.xml** in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">   
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>    
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="7dip"
        android:topRightRadius="7dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dip" />
</shape>
```

**Java file**

```
public class WhiteRectangle extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

**The output is**

[image: White rectangle as background]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an inner linear/relative layout with background set to white. :)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
android:background="@drawable/img_list_background_repeater"
```